# Multi Social Platforms at One Web Page

Tags: facebook, spring, api, jsf, twitter

The page that i need to code should include a construction like that :

"The user should be able to login Facebook, Twitter, Gmail, Linkedin (the list may go on). After that he should be able to view the news feed of his Facebook acc., tweets of his Twitter acc. and the others like that. I aim to code with Java Web Technologies (JSF, Spring etc.)."

I can struggle with it, but if anyone knows how to do it by the easiest or most practical way. I would appreciate.

Thanks.

Comment: Spring Social is ideal for what you're after [see here](http://projects.spring.io/spring-social/)

Comment: I was about to read an article about it. If you say that this will make it easier, i'll focus on it. Thanks a lot.